# Is a file on the same filesystem as another file in python?

Tags: python, filesystems

Is there a simple way of finding out if a file is on the same filesystem as another file?

The following command:

```
import shutil
shutil.move('filepatha', 'filepathb')
```

will try and rename the file (if it's on the same filesystem), otherwise it will copy it, then unlink.

I want to find out before calling this command whether it will preform the quick or slow option, how do I do this?

Comment: why do you need to know that, again?

Comment: it's to be performed by a distributed task engine across a number of machines, want to get an estimate of whether it'll be really fast or really slow so as to know how to split up the tasks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `os.stat` (on a filename) or `os.fstat` (on a file descriptor). The `st_dev` of the result will be the device number. If they are on the same file system, it will be the same in both.

```
import os

def same_fs(file1, file2):
    dev1 = os.stat(file1).st_dev
    dev2 = os.stat(file2).st_dev
    return dev1 == dev2
```